# Exclude the logo part of visited/hover effect in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a static code below use for navigation,

```
<div class="nav__show-hide--800 step-asia__grid">
  <div class="step-asia__grid-12--col-5">
    <div class="nav__left">
      <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/about.php">About Us</a>
      <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/whatwedo.php">What We Do</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-asia__grid-12--col-2">
    <div class="nav__logo nav__logo--height">
      <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/" id="logo"><img src="assets/image/logo-1.png" alt="Step Asia Logo"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-asia__grid-12--col-5">
    <div class="nav__right">
      <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/how-it-works.php">How It Works</a>
      <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery for which determine the current page and will add and active class to make an underline as hover effect to indicate the current page visited by the user

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[href]").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
      if (! $('#logo')) {
        $(this).addClass("active");         
      }
    }
  });
});
```

but I would like to exclude this part

```
<a href="http://localhost/step-asia/" id="logo"><img src="assets/image/logo-1.png" alt="Step Asia Logo"></a>
```

Is there any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.not()` to exclude a particular element from selector.

```
$("[href]").not("#logo").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");         
    }
});
```

or eventually instead of `.not()` or `:not()` you can directly step into the *if*:

```
if (this.id !== "logo" && this.getAttribute("href") === window.location.href) {
```

Comment: Also you could rather `$(this).attr("href")` instead of `this.href` - because it gives different results. Simply because `this.href` != `this.getAttribute("href")`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using simple css.
In your case:

```
.active #logo:hover{
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

You add the class active to the logo, but this will overwrite that.